# Visual Studio Mac - Android Build - Enable Developer Instrumentation cannot be disabled

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I'm on a Mac (Catalina OS) running Visual Studio for Mac Community (version 8.5 build 3183).
I've created a Xamarin solution targeting both Android and iOS.

For my Android Build options, for the Release configuration, I want to uncheck the "Enable Developer Instrumentation (debugging and profiling)" checkbox. However, the box is checked and disabled. What am I missing? It's my understanding that for a Release build I want that box unchecked.

Thanks.

[image: Disabled Checkbox]

Comment: Try to remove it manually in csproj. `<DevInstrumentationEnabled>True</DevInstrumentationEnabled>`

Comment: And change `<DebugType>full</DebugType>`  to `<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>`

Comment: I opened file "ImageSlider.Android.csproj" in VisualStudio and  this is part of my Property Section:  
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
....
</PropertyGroup>

Setting DebugSymbols to False would not stay when saved. 
DebugType I changed from "Portable" to pdbonly but checkbox in screenshot of question is still checked and disabled.

Comment: Try to remove debugtype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it!
Opened "Project Options" for the Android Application.
Pick the "Release" configuration.
Go to Build | Compiler options. Set the Debug Information's drop-down to "None"
Go to Build | Android Build and you will see that the "Enable Developer Instrumentation" checkbox is now unchecked.

**Set Debug to "None"**
[image: Set Debug to "None"]

**Enable Developer Instrumentation checkbox is cleared**
[image]

Comment: oh. Thanks. Newbie mistake. Done.